# Semaphores only working at the end

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I've got a weird problem with my code. It is suppoused to use Linux Semaphores to prevent 3 "trains" to enter the track at the same time. so the output must be something like:
Entra Peru
Sale Peru
Entra Bolivia
Sale Bolivia
Entra Colombia
Sale Colombia
...
(10 times)

And it doesent, first enter the 3 of them and then the 3 of them get out. But, at the last cycle it works as it should. So, any ideas? Heres the source code:

```
/*semaphore.h*/
struct sembuf {
   ushort  sem_num;        /* semaphore index in array */
   short   sem_op;         /* semaphore operation */
   short   sem_flg;        /* operation flags */
};


int seminit(int idsem, int value){
   int semid = semget(idsem, 1, IPC_CREAT);
   return semid;
}

void semwait(int idsem){
  int semid = semget(idsem, 0, IPC_EXCL);
  struct sembuf sops={semid, -1, 1};

  int op = semop (semid, sops, 1);
}

void semsignal(int idsem){
  int semid = semget(idsem, 0, IPC_EXCL);
  struct sembuf sops={semid, 1, 1};
  int op = semop (semid,sops, 1);
}
```

And this:

```
/*semaforos.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include "semaphores.h"

#define CICLOS 10


char *pais[3]={"Peru","Bolivia","Colombia"};

int *g;

void proceso(int i)
{
   int k;
   int l;

   int semid=seminit(i, -1);
   printf("\nSEMID: %d\n",semid);
   for(k=0;k<CICLOS;k++)
   {
      semwait(i);
   //Entrada a la seccción crítica
      printf("Entra %s\n",pais[i]);
      fflush(stdout);
      sleep(rand()%3);
      printf("- %s Sale\n",pais[i]);
      semsignal(i%3);
   // Salida de la sección crítica
      sleep(rand()%3);   // Espera aleatoria fuera de la sección crítica
   }
   exit(0); // Termina el proceso
}

int main()
{
   int pid;
   int status;
   int args[3];
   int i;
   srand(getpid());
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      pid=fork(); // Crea un nuevo proceso hijo que ejecuta la función proceso()
      if(pid==0)
         proceso(i);
   }

   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      pid = wait(&status);
 }
```

Comment: They both are idsem, to stop the current semaphore... The -1 and 1 is to add or substract value to the semaphore. Pass zero where?... I tried it here: 

sops={semid, -1, 1};   --->  sops={0, -1, 1};

But it didint work ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the semaphore work correctly, the code should create one semaphore, and use that semaphore for all three processes. Your code seems to create a separate semaphore for each process. Also, after creating the semaphore, the code should initialize the value of the semaphore to 1, so that the semaphore is ready to be taken.

Here's how I would write the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define SEM_RA    (SEM_R | SEM_A)
#define SEM_FLAGS (SEM_RA | (SEM_RA >> 3) | (SEM_RA >> 6))
#define CICLOS 10

static void error( const char *msg )
{
    perror( msg );
    exit( 1 );
}

void waitSem( int semid, int semnum )
{
    struct sembuf operations = { semnum, -1, 0 };

    if ( semop( semid, &operations, 1 ) < 0 )
        error( __func__ );
}

void signalSem( int semid, int semnum )
{
    struct sembuf operations = { semnum, 1, 0 };

    if ( semop( semid, &operations, 1 ) < 0 )
        error( __func__ );
}

void proceso( char *pais, int semID )
{
    int k;

    for ( k = 0; k < CICLOS; k++ )
    {
        waitSem( semID, 0 );
        // Entrada a la sección crítica
        printf( "Entra %s ", pais );
        fflush( stdout );
        sleep( arc4random_uniform( 3 ) );   // Espera aleatoria dentro de la sección crítica
        printf("- %s Sale\n", pais );
        signalSem( semID, 0 );
        // Salida de la sección crítica
        sleep( arc4random_uniform( 3 ) );   // Espera aleatoria fuera de la sección crítica
    }

    exit(0); // Termina el proceso
}

char *paises[3] = { "Peru", "Bolivia", "Colombia" };

int main( void )
{
    int i, semID, status;
    pid_t pid;

    // create the one semaphore that will be used by all three child processes
    if ( (semID = semget( 0x1001, 1, IPC_CREAT | SEM_FLAGS )) < 0 )
        error( "Unable to create semaphore" );

    // set the semaphore count to 1 so it's ready to be taken
    if ( semctl( semID, 0, SETVAL, 1 ) < 0 )
        error( "Unable to initialize semaphore" );

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        pid = fork();       // Crea un nuevo proceso hijo que ejecuta la función proceso()
        if ( pid == 0 )
            proceso( paises[i], semID );
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        wait( &status );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.... What are SEM_R and SEM_A because it creates a compiling error D:

Comment: Those are defined in <sys/sem.h>.  `#define SEM_A 0200` `#define SEM_R 0400` Note that they are octal constants, so the leading zero is very important.

Comment: This are the permit umbers right? For writing and reading? (Thank you in advance for all the help)

Comment: @ShaulaMontoya Yes, those are the same numbers that are used for file system permissions, just like the `chmod` command.